# How to get column names with Dyalog APL after an SQL query?

Tags: apl, dyalog

I am working with Dyalog APL and having trouble with getting the column names of a table **resulted from an SQL query**. More precisely, I am working with the workspaces (WS) `sqapl` and `LOADDATA` provided by Dyalog. Although the functions `LoadSQL` and `SQA.Do` from the `LOADDATA` and `sqapl` WS, respectively, make it possible to import a table resulting from an SQL query (e.g. a join of some tables), they do not return the column names.

Let's say we are in the following setting:

We have the following query that combines some tables

```
qry←'select COL_1, COL_2, C.* '
qry,←'from TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B, TABLE3 C '
qry,←'where C.COL_3 = B.COL_3 '
qry,←'and A.COL_4 = B.COL_4'
```

and want to get the resulting table together with the column names. We can call the functions `LoadSQL` and `SQA.Do` as follows:

```
⍝ With WS LOADDATA
tbl1←LoadSQL ('MySQL' 'psw' 'userID')qry    ⍝ tbl1 is a table without column names

⍝ With WS sqapl
SQA.Init ''                                 ⍝ Initiate
SQA.Connect 'C1' 'MySQL' 'psw' 'userID'     ⍝ Connect to a service

tbl2←⊃⊃(SQA.Do 'C1' qry)[3]                ⍝ Keep only resulting table (3rd element)
                                            ⍝ again without column names
```

Note that the WS `sqapl` offers the function `SQA.Columns` which I can use as follows

```
(2⊃SQA.Columns 'C1' 'MY_TABLE')[;4]
```

This works fine **provided the table MY_TABLE exists already**, but I cannot make it work for a table that I get from a query as the one above. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're after is `SQA.Describe`. See the [documentation](https://docs.dyalog.com/latest/SQL%20Interface%20Guide.pdf#page=34).

Comment: That was a quick reply, thanks!